# M2: Useful SQL scripts to convert a "production" copy to dev?

Tags: magento2, database, magento-2.1, import

I'm just wondering if people have any useful SQL scripts/queries to *"flip"* a copy of a production site environment into a development environment?

I actually have my production copied to the development environment by our host, they make a clone copy, and make a few of the base changes to make the development site come up (base url, etc).

Are ALL the base store configurations stored in `core_config_data`?

Im looking for SQL scripts that people have found useful to quickly re-configure a site for testing. Things like payment methods (Id like to have a script to change them from prod to sandbox mode), store url, cookie setting, etc. I'd like to create/have a sql query to update all of these settings at once, to save a bunch of time.  Luckily, once this script is mostly working, it won't need to change often to continue to be useful.

Comment: "Are ALL the base store configurations stored in core_config_data?" - yes. And while SQL scripts are a possible solution, you might want something that's easier to maintain for more different environments at some point, then I can recommend checking out existing tools (my choice: https://github.com/LimeSoda/LimeSoda_EnvironmentConfiguration)

Answer (score 4):

You could use **[n98-magerun2.phar](https://github.com/netz98/n98-magerun2)** to get a GZIP-ed SQL dump of the database. I usually run something like:

```
n98-magerun.phar db:dump --strip="@stripped" -c gzip
```

This typically gives you a file like `date_time_dbname.sql.gz`. Use `n98-magerun.phar db:dump --help` to see all options. I could imagine that you'd want to strip out the customer (sensitive) data most of the times.

After that, transport it from server to local environment and import it there. I usually run something like:

```
gunzip < date_time_dbname.sql.gz | mysql -uroot -p local_dbname
```

It can be very useful to keep a file in your local somewhere with additional `UPDATE` queries to update entries of the `core_config_data` table to your local environment configuration. Think of `web/%secure/base_url`:

**`live2local.sql`**:

```
UPDATE `core_config_data` SET `value` = 'http://magento.local/'
  WHERE `path` = 'web/unsecure/base_url';
UPDATE `core_config_data` SET `value` = 'http://magento.local/'
  WHERE `path` = 'web/unsecure/base_url';
```

Do not forget to add queries to update cookie params if you have explicitly set them on your production environment. I usually also add queries to update configs/credentials for PSP, ERP and other API's from production endpoint and credentials to testing endpoint and credentials.

You can run this right after the import command:

```
mysql -uroot -p local_dbname < live2local.sql
```